# build.xml Failed to send email: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first

Tags: java, xml, email, ant, build.xml

Every time the build gets failed and shows "Problem while sending mime mail:"!

The build has finished. A details report of this build is aatched

I already have added javax.mail.jar, mail.jar and activation.jar in my project lib folder and ant home.

Would appreciate if someone can guide me resolving this.

Comment: So there is a problem sending mail. What is the stacktrace? That might help diagnose what is going on.

Comment: sendMail:
      [zip] Building zip: C:\Users\ADMIN\workspace\Bitesize\testng-xslt\Report.z
ip
     [mail] Sending email: Notification of TESTNG build
     [mail] Failed to send email: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first.
 bi4sm2300490pbc.56 - gsmtp

BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\ADMIN\workspace\Bitesize\build.xml:63: Problem while sending mime mail:


Total time: 50 seconds

Comment: Looks like it's a message from the remote smtp server saying it won't accept plain text connections.